# Java 8 Time API / Is current time in time frame

Tags: java, java-time

I would like to check if the current time is in a defined frame. I tried the following:

```
if (LocalTime.now().isBefore(config.getEnd()) && LocalTime.now().isAfter(config.getStart())) {
    ...
}
```

`config.getEnd()` and `config.getStart()` return `LocalTime`s in the format "HH:mm:ss".

This works as long as the starttime is before the endtime. But if this program should execute in the middle of the night between 23:00:00 and 02:00:00 then of course it doesn't. With the old java.util.date I would deduct 1 day from the starttime but I have no days here.

Does anyone know an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200991/between-java-time-localtime-next-day

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, thanks. I googled for different expressions :/

Comment: It's only because I remembered it, it's hard to search for yeah.